# push to a temporary array within a function

Tags: solidity, arrays

I come from nodejs and this seems odd to me..
can't seem to push anything to a temporary array.

```
    function get_unconfirmed() public view returns (address[] memory, uint[] memory, uint[] memory) {
   
        address     [] memory _address;
        uint        [] memory _wei;
        uint256     [] memory _ssboe;

        for(uint i = 0; i < deposit_request.length; i++){
            
            if(deposit_request[i]._confirmed){
                _address.push(deposit_request[i]._owner);
                _wei.push(deposit_request[i]._value);
                _ssboe.push(deposit_request[i]._ssboe);
            }

        }

        return (_address, _wei, _ssboe);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible memory arrays have a fixed size and you need to allocate the space previous assigning it.

For example something like this:

```
    address[] memory _address;

    uint256 count = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i < deposit_request.length; i++){
        if (deposit_request[i]._confirmed){
            ++count;
        }
    }

    _address = new address[](count);
```